# How do I deploy NodeJS server that's for a React Native App to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, hosting

I have an app using React Native as its frontend, and NodeJS as backend, and it also has a cloud MySQL instance. I want to deploy the app to the public and show it to someone as demo using Heroku or maybe other hosting services. 

I want to publish my React Native App with Expo, but am not sure how/ where to host my nodeJS server so that the mobile app can access it.

Comment: I don't think that's either possible or recommended. Always when u wanted to pass on the APK to someone generate the apk which will also have the js bundle through offline or appcenter or playstore alpha release or firebase distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow Heroku official document to deploy your NodeJS server.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Then you can access the domain provided by Heroku just exactly like on your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for deploying React native/expo app to heroku:

1: set heroku buildpack as static: >heroku buildpacks:set heroku-community/static

2: Add static.json for static buildtype: { "root": "web-build/", "routes": { "/**": "index.html" } } More settings here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#configuration

3: npm run build (package.json: "build": "expo build:web") --> Creates web-build folder

git add .

git commit

git push heroku master

heroku open

Comment: Please check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.